# UISegmentedControl selected Segment always -1

Tags: xcode, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I subclassed UISegmentedControl in order to trigger the valueChanged method which works fine. Now when I select a segment the index is always -1.
I am on Xcode 6 beta 4, I can't find what I am doing wrong.
The subclass:

```
import UIKit

class MySegCotrl: UISegmentedControl {

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)  {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let current = self.selectedSegmentIndex
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    println("Current:\(current)")
    println("Self.selectedSegmentIndex:\(self.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    if current == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
        self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }
}

}
```

The valueChanged method in my UIViewController class

```
@IBOutlet var segCotrRelevanz: MySegCotrl!

@IBAction func relevanChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("sender.selectedSegmentIndex:\(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    println("segCotrRelevanz.selectedSegmentIndex:\(segCotrRelevanz.selectedSegmentIndex)")

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == segCotrRelevanz.selectedSegmentIndex {
        println("Same")
    }

}
```

The output:

```
Current:-1
Self.selectedSegmentIndex:-1
sender.selectedSegmentIndex:-1
segCotrRelevanz.selectedSegmentIndex:-1
Same
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change method to touchesBegan not touchesEnded, left all as it should be:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let current = self.selectedSegmentIndex
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    println("Current:\(current)")
    println("Self.selectedSegmentIndex:\(self.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    if current == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
        self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was, that I call super.touchesBegan even though I need to call super.touchesEnded. Your solution works for iOS 6 and lower though, thank you!